# Concrete Pier Question

Tags: concrete, framing, foundation

I am remodelling a home that has an addition built on a slab (assume 4") with 2x4 exterior walls.  I want to frame a new floor to raise the surface almost 2 feet.  The room is ~16' x ~28' and my plan is to run a girder down the middle longways, hang joists, box it all in, and tie the box to the existing wall studs.  I want to support it with conrete piers with no wood touching the slab.

A couple questions:

1. Under the girder should I pour new footers, 8" of gravel and 12" of concrete with piers formed on top?  Or would concrete blocks mortared to the top of the slab work?
2. Would the joist headers tied to the 2x4 wall be enough support or should I add piers to support the header?  Would there be concerns being up to the sole plate/near the edge of the slab?

Comment: While this seems reasonably straightforward, providing a drawing is always a good idea. Also, on what do you "assume" a 4" slab?

Comment: I assume 4" slab because that's the smallest you could pour for an addition, and the previous owner was a chaeapskate.

Comment: Why not just run a couple courses of CMU along the long walls, install sill plates, and set your 16' joists on top?

Comment: Would that work on top of the slab?  I still need some passthrough for utilities and HVAC, I assume small gaps would be fine?